# Need explanation on sending data from adapter to fragment

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

I want to send data from an adapter to a fragment that is already open.
In the main activity, there are two fragments already open, fragment A and fragment B. In fragment A, I have a RecyclerView and CardView placed. When one of the card views is clicked, I want to send its data to fragment B. And I get an NPE when calling mCallbacks.

```
if (mCallbacks != null){
     mCallbacks.onItemClicked(strStockName);}
```

In this case, I used an interface. But I need more explanation about it.

Here is my adapter's code:

```
public class adapterStock extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterStock.ViewHolder> {
   private String[] stockNameDataSet;
   private Context mContext;

   //==============================================
   //---- interface
   public interface Callbacks{
       public void onItemClicked(String StockName);
   }
   private Callbacks mCallbacks;

   //==============================================


   public adapterStock(Context context, String[] DataSet){
       stockNameDataSet = DataSet;
       mContext = context;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public adapterStock.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cv_stock, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String strStockName = stockNameDataSet[position];
        holder.tbxStockName.setText(stockNameDataSet[position]);

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               Snackbar.make(view, "Stock "+strStockName, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               if (mCallbacks != null){
                mCallbacks.onItemClicked(strStockName);
               }

          }
       });
    }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return stockNameDataSet.length;
   }

   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       public View view;
       public TextView tbxStockName;
       public CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
           super (v);
           tbxStockName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cvTbxItemStockName);
           cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cvStock);
    }
   }

   public void setCallbacks(Callbacks callbacks){
       this.mCallbacks = callbacks;
   }
}
```

And here is fragment A:

```
public class AFrag extends Fragment implements adapterStock.Callbacks {
      private String strStockName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_A, container, false);
    tbxStock = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tbxR);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClicked(String StockName) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stock terpilih " + StockName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tbxStock.setText(strStockName);
}
}
```

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make that data as public in your main activity. then you can access that data in both the fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include, setCallbacks(this) in your fragment A once adapterStock instance is created.

Comment: i'm sorry, can you tell me more about that code (how implement in code)?

Comment: After you create object of your adapter class adapterstock do adapterstock.setCallbacks(this).

Comment: Refer https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

setCallbacks(this) in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
     public adapterStock(Context context, String[] DataSet){
        stockNameDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }
```

to this

```
 public adapterStock(Context context, String[] DataSet, Callbacks mCallbacks){
        stockNameDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
        this.mCallbacks=mCallbacks;
    }
```

in fragment's `adapterStock` instance, pass the `mCallbacks` as `this` (i.e., `new adapterStock(context, dataset,this)`)

**note:** two other answers also correct